# Scanning user input into a .txt file in c

Tags: c, file, loops

Currently stuck on a project trying to put number given by the user into a .txt file. It should be in a loop until the user enters 0. The first two numbers are integers and the last is a float. my current code infinitely loops the `printf` and does not allow for the `scanf`. I must use `fwrite` because he wants it to be in binary mode. The problem is in the loop I just keep getting

> Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price):

Here is my code for the project.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("This program stores a business inventory. \n");

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("inventory.txt", "w+b");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open a file. \n");
        return 0;
    }
    int a[2];
    float b;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price): \n");


        scanf("%d", &a[0]);
        scanf("%d", &a[1]);
        scanf("%f", &b);

        fwrite(a, sizeof(a[0]),sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), fp);
        fwrite(&b, sizeof(b),1,fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The project wants me to "Write a program to repeatedly ask the user to enter information regarding inventory for a business (item part
number, quantity, price) and then saves the information to a file called inventory.txt. The program stops the loop when the user enters 0 for the part number."

The user inputs are 3, 1, 3.4

Comment: To write numbers to a text file please use `fprintf`. How can the output file be a text file *and* a binary file? But to the question, you are not testing *anything* let alone to result in a break from the loop. That's why it is infinite.

Comment: may I suggest my [beginners' guide away from scanf](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)?

Comment: @WeatherVane but it isn't a text file. Why it's still named `.txt` remains a secret of the OP ;)

Comment: Cannot reproduce your "my current code infinitely loops the printf and does not allow for the scanf".

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to figure that out, the project wants the name of the file to be inventory.txt and also want to use fwrite.

Comment: whats your actual question? If you want to exit the loop then test for ==0

Comment: Post the exact user input you use would help illuminate the trouble.

Comment: You have an infinite loop without any condition to break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
while(1)
{
    printf("Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price): \n");


    scanf("%d", &a[0]);
    if(a[0] == 0)
        break
    scanf("%d", &a[1]);
    scanf("%f", &b);

    fwrite(a, sizeof(a[0]),sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), fp);
    fwrite(&b, sizeof(b),1,fp);
}
```